# Using Netbeans, why does Ruby debug not display multibytes string properly?

Tags: ruby, debugging, netbeans

The env are: netbeans(v=6.9.1), ruby-debug-base (v=0.10.4), ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16) ,ruby(v=1.8.7)

During the process of debuging a Ruby script, the debuger can not display multibytes properly and always displays "Binary Data" for multibytes string in variable window view:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'
str = "调试程序"
str = str.mb_chars
puts "length: #{str.length}"
```

BTW, I tried 0.4.16, 0.4.11 for ruby-debug-ide, but they have the same output.

Can someone tell me how to make it to display the multibyte string properly in the debug variable window view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that Ruby 1.8.7 had the beginning of multi-byte support. You probably need to define your $KCODE value for your source. See [The $KCODE Variable and jcode Library](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/the_kcode_variable_and_jcode_library)

Ruby 1.9.2 has much better support for it, so give it a try if that's an option.

---

This is from messing around with 1.9.2 and irb:

```
Greg:~ greg$ irb -f
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2"
irb(main):002:0> str = "调试程序"
=> "调试程序"
irb(main):003:0> str
=> "调试程序"
irb(main):004:0> str.each_char.to_a
=> ["调", "试", "程", "序"]
irb(main):005:0> str.each_byte.to_a
=> [232, 176, 131, 232, 175, 149, 231, 168, 139, 229, 186, 143]
irb(main):006:0> str.valid_encoding?
=> true
irb(main):007:0> str.codepoints
=> #<Enumerator: "调试程序":codepoints>
irb(main):008:0> str.each_codepoint.to_a
=> [35843, 35797, 31243, 24207]
irb(main):009:0> str.each_codepoint.to_a.map { |i| i.to_s(16) }
=> ["8c03", "8bd5", "7a0b", "5e8f"]
irb(main):010:0> str.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):011:0>
```

And, if I run the following in Textmate while 1.9.2 is set as my default:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
puts RUBY_VERSION
str = "调试程序"
puts str
```

which outputs:

```
# >> 1.9.2
# >> 调试程序
```

Ruby Debug19 gets mad with the same code so I need to look into what its problem is.

Comment: Thank Greg very much. I ever tried to set -KU running time parameter, and during the process of debug it always display Binary Data. so I will compromise on the debug issue. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: Debuggers tend to display binary data as escaped values. If all the data fits within a particular Unicode code-set it can make an assumption that it's some form of text, but if the values are from many code-sets it will probably revert to escaping because it doesn't know if the string actually contains text or if it's a variable containing some sort of binary data. Some debuggers allow casting to a particular type of variable, like a string or a structure, so you can educate the debugger how you want to view things, but without your help it would use escaping or a hex display.

Comment: It's been ages since I did it, but I think the debugger in NetBeans will let you coerce values when displaying them in the Java debugger at least for Java. NetBeans and Java are very well integrated; I don't think they've managed to do the same with Ruby yet.