# how to set jcode library for rubymine debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

I'm trying to debug arabic text in rubymine. A quick [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362138/using-netbeans-why-does-ruby-debug-not-display-multibytes-string-properly) reveals that I need to set $KCODE env variable to 'U' and require the jcode library..

that works fine for me on irb, but I can't figure out how to do it for the rubymine debugger. Setting the debugger [env variable](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-ruby.html) didn't help. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically i fixed it another way: by putting encoding settings (ie `#encoding: UTF-8`) on the top of the and that fixed it.